# Swift UI - Why is UI shown in preview not as same as renderd on a physical device or simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am new to IOS development, and I am not able to understand this behaviour

Can someone please explain me why is the preview is not as same as rendered in a physical device?

Problem is, in the preview there is no padding at the top and bottom of the UI but in simulator/Physical device I can see this padding, not able to understand why

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because the frame of the main window is not filled to the screen.
This issue may have different reasons but one more regular is:

> missing the `UILaunchScreen` key in the `info.plist` (sounds weird but its true ‍♂️)

<sub>**Note:** It's hard to find out what is the exact issue by the information you have provided, but you can create a brand new project and do your code there if you are unable to find the exact issue.</sub>

Comment: Thank you
It works in a new project

But what if this issue happens with one screen in a big project, starting a new project and copy pasting everything is not good option right?

Comment: Just check the differences with the new and your current project to find the issue ;)

Comment: You should bring your big project to check what is the exact issue ;) I hope this answer helped you